# Error : src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ElementosType' to a(n) 'type definition' component

Tags: xml, xsd, xquery

i have already seen others solution but basically can't resolve mine cause it says is missing a complextype but it's not true cause i have the complextype in the same xsd file .

the code is here

complextype:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.ipp.estg.pt/Dados_clientes"
 elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <!-- Elemento completo -->


  <!-- COMPLEX TYPE RELATIVO AOS ELEMENTOS DA FAMILIA  -->

  <xs:complexType name="ElementosType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="nome" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="data_nascimento" type="xs:date" />
      <xs:element name="pais" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="cidade_origem" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>`
```

the other complextype i used to call him

```
<xs:complexType name="FamiliasType">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="clientes" type="ElementosType" maxOccurs="7"/>
  <xs:element name="preferencia_dias" type="PreferenciasType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="5" />
</xs:sequence>
```

</xs:complexType>

The error says : **src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ElementosType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.xsd(src-resolve)**

I really dont know how to solve i already tried different ways.

Comment: If the elements and types belong to a namespace you can do `<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.ipp.estg.pt/Dados_clientes" xmlns:tns="http://www.ipp.estg.pt/Dados_clientes" ...>` and then use `xs:element name="clientes" type="tns:ElementosType"`. Don't remember whether XSD 1 allows to designate a default type namespace.

Comment: worked , but the preferenciasType is doing the same error , i use the same prefix ?

Comment: Well, `preferenciasType` appears nowhere in your posted XSD, so it's not just a reference formulation problem -- the whole definition is missing.  Note also that case matters.

Comment: If the type is from the same schema/target namespace, then, yes, use the same prefix. I think doing `xmlns="http://www.ipp.estg.pt/Dados_clientes"` also suffices, then the `xs:element name="clientes" type="ElementosType"` would look for the type in the default namespace.